# What exception should be thrown when validation fails?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

We have a Create operation that runs validation on the entity that was passed in. If this entity is not valid, what exception should be thrown?

Initially, we were going to throw ApplicationException, but after some research it seems this is incorrect: (from an article on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229007.aspx)):

**X DO NOT** throw or derive from `ApplicationException`.

Should we create a custom Exception and inherit from `ApplicationException`?

Is there an Exception that exists in the .NET framework that we should be using?

Or maybe, should we not throw an exception at all?

I am not sure...

Some more detail:

In this specific case, the Create method create an address change request. Business rules state that there can only be one address change request at a time. The validation error can come from one of two scenarios:

1. A property of the entity is not set, or is set to an incorrect value
2. An address change request already exists.

Comment: `InvalidArgumentException` seems right in your case. Eventually you can create a custom exception that fits your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should throw an `InvalidArgumentException`

Comment: I am not sure if that is the correct way to go in our specific case. I have updated my question to give more detail. Do you still feel that `InvalidArgumentException` would be appropriate for case #2?

Comment: In the second case I would throw a custom exception